# How do you perform a MYSQL After Update Trigger Insert Loop?

Tags: mysql, trigger, update, insert

I have 3 mysql tables, one called `batches`, one called `base_formula` and one called `raw_materials_stock`.

I want to perform an after update trigger on the `batches` table to insert information into the `raw_materials_stock` table based on information from the `base_formula` table.

**Batches Table**

batch_id, complete_dt, base_id

**Base Formula Table**

base_id, raw_material_id, percentage

**Raw Material Stock Table**

batch_id,raw_material_id,use_date,quantity

**Batches Trigger**

```
IF OLD.complete_dt is NULL and NEW.complete_dt is not null and (select b.raw_material_id from base_formula b where b.base_id=new.base_id) is not null  THEN 

INSERT INTO raw_materials_stock (batch_id,raw_material_id,use_date,quantity) 
VALUES(
new.batch_id,
(select b.raw_material_id from base_formula b where b.base_id=new.base_id),
now(),
(select ((new.volume/100)*b.percent)*-1 from base_formula b where b.base_id=new.base_id)); 

END IF
```

**Issue**

This issue i have is the `base_formula` table has more than 1 row with the same `base_id`. How can i use a loop to insert all of the rows with the same `base_id` into the `raw_material_stock` table?

Comment: You can try build a cursor 
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restructure your query

```
INSERT INTO raw_materials_stock 
  (batch_id,raw_material_id,use_date,quantity) 
    SELECT 
       new.batch_id, 
       b.raw_material_id, 
       now(), 
       ((new.volume/100)*b.percent)*-1 
    from base_formula b where b.base_id=new.base_id;
```